# C - out of index element has same address as integer

Tags: c, arrays, loops

So I have this program that prints the addresses of each variable and changes the values of an integer array 'a'. When SOMETHING is 4, the values printed are as expected. However, when I change SOMETHING to 5, the value of i changes to 40, which is what would've been the value of a[4] if it existed. Why does it do this?

```
#define SIZE 4
#define SOMETHING 4

int index = 0;
int i;
int k = 10;
int a[SIZE] = {0, 0, 0, 0};
int j = 10;

printf("Address of the variables:\n");
printf("%lx -> &j\n", (unsigned long)&j);
for (index = 0; index < SIZE; index++) {
    printf("%lx -> &a[%d]\n", (unsigned long) &a[index], index);
}

printf("%lx -> &k\n", (unsigned long)&k);
printf("%lx -> &i\n", (unsigned long)&i);
printf("\n");


printf("Initial values: ");
printf("i = %d, j = %d, k = %d\n", i, j, k);
printf("a = {%d, %d, %d, %d}\n", a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3]);
printf("\n");


for (i = 0; i < SOMETHING; i++) {
    a[i] = i * 10;
    printf("i = %d, j = %d, k = %d\t\t", i, j, k);
    printf("a = {%d, %d, %d, %d}\n", a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3]);
}

return 0;
```

Comment: `(unsigned long)&k` is implementation defined and likely wrong. If you want to print an address, use to correct type specifier in your format string (`%p`) and provide a `void *` (cast the pointer appropriately).

Comment: I did not get `i=40`.   I always got `i=4`.

Answer (score 2):

Accessing an array out of bound will invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Result can be ***anything***.

In your case, array `a` has 4 (`SIZE`) elements, so the valid index will be [0,3]. So,

- in case, `SOMETHING` is 4,  you have

  ```
  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
  ```

  which limits the index to `3`.
- OTOH, if you make `SOMETHING` as 5,  you have

  ```
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  ```

  which actually attempts to access `a[4]` which is out of bound memory, creating UB.

FWIW, to print an address, use the `%p` format specifier and cast the argument to `void*`.

Comment: Note: the OP could be asking either "why is it allowed to do this?" **or** "why does it actually do this in practice?", while this answer answers the former.